# what is the purpose of php.ini file in magento directory?

Tags: magento2, php

There's a `php.ini` file in magento directory. Does this file overrides the global `php.ini` settings? I'm making changes in that but they're not reflecting after restarting wamp. Is that a sample file and changes must be made in global `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `php.ini` under Magento root folder  is a sample setting for Magento 2. You need to change the config in global file.